Dropped my SSD; no longer mountable, but partially readable to a limited degree, what happened?
tl;dr:

I dropped my laptop with SSD inside
The drive is no longer mountable or fsck-able (the dreaded input/output error)
However, the disk is still intact/working enough to read the partition table and check the encryption password
If connected externally via USB, the drive is totally invisible, not recognized at all
What happened?
Is there any way to fix it?

Full details:
I have an old ThinkPad T420 from 2012. I run Ubuntu 20.04 and the main partition is encrypted. A few days ago I dropped it. It immediately turned off, and will no longer boot to the main drive.
The main boot drive is an SSD (Samsung 870 EVO) that is connected to the laptop via a caddy which adapts the drive to fit into the optical drive bay.
Although there is no visible damage to either the SSD or the adapter, my first thought was that the damage was to the connector/adapter or something like that had gotten either damaged or jostled loose. So I removed the SSD from the laptop and attached it to a SATA to USB adapter. This was a total failure. I plugged it into to a couple of different computers and the drive seemed totally invisible (no new device in /dev, no entry in lsusb). (The SATA to USB adpater itself works fine when I tested it with a different HDD.)
However, if I put the SSD back in its original location/caddy and boot to Linux via USB, it turns out the drive is not totally invisible, but seemingly not actually usable either.
I can see the partition table for the drive:
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda
Disk /dev/sda: 465.76 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk model: Samsung SSD 870 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xe62c1c13

Device     Boot   Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *       2048   1050623   1048576   512M  b W95 FAT32
/dev/sda2       1052670 976771071 975718402 465.3G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       1052672   2549759   1497088   731M 83 Linux
/dev/sda6       2551808 976771071 974219264 464.5G 83 Linux

The drive is encrypted, so I can't just mount it directly, but need to go thru some rigamarole first:
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo cryptsetup open /dev/sda6 ssd
Enter passphrase for /dev/sda6: 

if I type in the wrong password, it rejects me:
Warning: keyslot operation could fail as it requires more than available memory.
No key available with this passphrase.

but if i type in the right password, it lets me in and the device /dev/mapper/ssd appears as expected.
Now there's one more step of rigamarole. The command is sudo vgchange -ay, which should cause the device /dev/vgubuntu/root to appear. When I first tried, this command worked, but at the moment, it no longer does anything (things are deteriorating with the passage of time, see below).
At this point, you should be able to mount /dev/vgubuntu/root, but mount fails with a generic "input/output error" (don't have the exact error at hand at the moment). fsck also fails with "input/output error" and a second error something like "no superblock found".
At the moment I am running ddrescue to see what can be recovered:
sudo ddrescue --idirect /dev/sda /media/ubuntu/whatever/rescue.img /media/ubuntu/whatever/rescue.log

It does seem to be doing something, but very slow and I am a bit skeptical it will really succeed.
One other note: the problem seems to get worse and you get more errors the longer the drive is plugged in. For example, initially you can read the partition table with sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda as I showed above. However, eventually this will stop working:
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda
fdisk: cannot open /dev/sda: Invalid argument

But it will start working again if you pop the drive out and back in again.
What's happened to the disk? Can anything be done to recover it?

“What's happened to the disk?” - My honest assessment? It’s broken. While SSDs have no moving mechanical parts they are still delicate electronics.

ddrescue probably can't get anything from an encrypted device partition like sda or sda6. Wouldn't a rescue tool  work better on /dev/mapper/ssd than on /dev/sda?

@Ramhound Fair enough, I certainly can't argue with that conclusion :) Whatever false beliefs I had that SSDs would be robust to mechanical shock have been disproven by these events. With that said, although the drive is certainly "broken" in the sense that it can't be used for everyday use, the ddrescue operation was mostly successful, the data appears to be mostly intact, and I can see my files. I will post a full update/answer when I have time.

Most likely, the shock knocked loose some tiny surface-mount part, which can be soldered back. After salvaging what you can, have the case popped open by someone with skills and equipment to handle microelectronics, if you can find a volunteer.

With regard to the first question:

What's happened to the disk?

I don't really know, though see the comments by DrMoishe Pippik and Ramhound for a partial explanation.
For the second question:

Can anything be done to recover it?

the answer is a clear yes. Whatever the problem was, the disk was not damaged too badly; ddrescue was able to recover almost all of the information from the disk, and I was able to pull all the files I needed.
I'll go over the full recovery process just in case it helps anyone else.
As I mentioned earlier, I had to attach the drive internally rather than via USB to be able to read it at all, so that's what I did here: booting into live Linux via USB stick, reading the damaged drive inside the computer, and copying to a backup drive connected via USB.
First step is to run ddrescue, which does basically exactly what it's advertised to. I used the guide here, but there's one important caveat: if you are using live Linux, don't be stupid like me and save the rescue log in the home directory which will disappear as soon as you restart.
So the initial command to run is
sudo ddrescue --idirect /dev/sdc /media/ubuntu/whatever/rescue.img /media/ubuntu/whatever/rescue.log

and the final output I saw was
     ipos:  497530 MB, non-trimmed:        0 B,  current rate:       0 B/s
     opos:  497530 MB, non-scraped:        0 B,  average rate:  13107 kB/s
non-tried:        0 B,  bad-sector:   55758 kB,    error rate:       0 B/s
  rescued:  500052 MB,   bad areas:    10222,        run time:  9h  2m 55s
pct rescued:   99.98%, read errors:   113242,  remaining time:          0s
                              time since last successful read:          0s
Scraping failed blocks... (forwards)
Finished                           

99.98% rescued on the first try, not too bad.
(One side note: Occasionally, ddrescue will fail with message ddrescue: /dev/sdc: Unaligned read error. Is sector size correct?. When this happens, pop the disk out then pop it back in, and re-run the exact same command (although make sure the device name hasn't changed e.g. from /dev/sdc to /dev/sdd) which will pick up where it left off.)
After the initial run, you can try retrying, which uses the exact same command except with the --retry-passes=N argument added. My experience was that each additional retry pass rescued an additional few hundred kB of data, but it was so slow for such a small amount of data, at a certain point I gave up.
Now you have your disk image with a few (10,000 or so) holes in it. If you like, you can make a copy of the image, just in case you screw up the first one.
At this point I was able to mount the filesystem of interest:
# At this point, do everything read-only (-r) to prevent modifying the image:
sudo kpartx -a -r /media/ubuntu/whatever/rescue.img
# The above command should have created devices corresponding to the partitions of the image.
# For me the partition of interest was /dev/mapper/loop14p6
sudo cryptsetup open /dev/mapper/loop14p6 try1
sudo vgchange -ay
# The above command should have created a mountable device, in my case /dev/vgubuntu/root
# both ro and noload are necessary for read-only case:
sudo mount -o ro,noload /dev/vgubuntu/root /path/to/mount/point

At this point I was able to see the full directory structure and all my files. I opened a few files up and everything seemed normal.
Before doing anything else, I wanted to determine which files would be corrupted (i.e. which files had data stored in the bad sectors that were unrecovered by ddrescue). There is a tool ddrutility which is supposed to do exactly this, but it didn't seem to work and I suspect it doesn't work with encrypted disks. So I wrote a couple of extremely quick-and-dirty python scripts to do the work. (Credit to this answer for telling me the debugfs commands to run)
Note that in the script below, it is essential that the partition_start_sectors value be correct!
If you have a simple partitioning scheme, you can just use fdisk -l to find it.
However, for setups with LUKS and LVM stuff, this is not sufficient.
Eventually, I found the command dmsetup table, which shows the needed information:
$ sudo dmsetup table
loop14p1: 0 1048576 linear 7:14 2048
loop14p2: 0 2 linear 7:14 1052670
loop14p5: 0 1497088 linear 7:14 1052672
loop14p6: 0 974219264 linear 7:14 2551808
try1: 0 974186496 crypt aes-xts-plain64 :64:logon:cryptsetup:b422c3bc-f3f7-4fea-ab8b-900437ccc302-d0 0 252:3 32768
vgubuntu-root: 0 972177408 linear 252:4 2048
vgubuntu-swap_1: 0 2007040 linear 252:4 972179456

So the relevant offset is 2551808 + 32768 + 2048.
Script 1 find filesystem block numbers and inodes associated with bad sectors in the recovery log:
# step1.py
import subprocess

partition_start_sectors = 2551808 + 32768 + 2048
partition_start_bytes = partition_start_sectors*512

ext4_block_size = 4096

with open('rescue.log') as f, open('inodes.log', 'w') as inodes_out, open('missing_inodes.log', 'w') as missing_out:
    for i, line in enumerate(f.readlines()):
        print(i)
        row = line.strip().split()
        if len(row)==3 and row[2] == '-':
            bad_sector_pos = int(row[0],16)
            print(f'sector_pos: {bad_sector_pos}')
            bad_sector_size = int(row[1],16)
            first_bad_block = (bad_sector_pos-partition_start_bytes)//ext4_block_size
            last_bad_block = (bad_sector_pos+bad_sector_size-1-partition_start_bytes)//ext4_block_size
            for bad_block in range(first_bad_block, last_bad_block+1):
                print(f'block: {bad_block}')
                output1 = subprocess.check_output(f'sudo debugfs -R "testb {bad_block}" /dev/vgubuntu/root', shell=True)
                if b'marked in use' in output1:
                    print('in use')
                    output2 = subprocess.check_output(f'sudo debugfs -R "icheck {bad_block}" /dev/vgubuntu/root', shell=True)
                    if b'block not found' in output2:
                        print('no inode found for this block')
                        print(f'{bad_sector_pos} {bad_block}', file=missing_out, flush=True)
                    else:
                        inode = int(output2.split(b'\n')[1].split(b'\t')[1])
                        print(f'inode: {inode}')
                        print(f'{bad_sector_pos} {bad_block} {inode}', file=inodes_out, flush=True)
                else:
                    print('not in use')

Script 2 find file names associated with inodes:
# step2.py

import subprocess

inodes = set()
with open('inodes.log') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        row = line.strip().split()
        try:
            inode = int(row[2])
            inodes.add(str(inode))
        except ValueError:
            pass
inodes = list(inodes)
print(len(inodes))

for i in range(0, len(inodes), 30):
    inodes_subset = inodes[i:i+30]
    inodes_found = set()
    output = subprocess.check_output('sudo debugfs -R "ncheck ' + ' '.join(inodes_subset) + '" /dev/vgubuntu/root', shell=True)
    for line in output.split(b'\n'):
        row = line.split(b'\t')
        if len(row) == 2 and row[0] != b'Inode':
            inode = int(row[0])
            path = row[1].decode('ascii')
            inodes_found.add(str(inode))
            print(f'{inode} {path}')
    if inodes_found != set(inodes_subset):
        print('not all inodes found:')
        print(f'missing inodes: {set(inodes_subset)-inodes_found}')

This identified about 250 files which were corrupted. Sure enough, when I tried opening the supposed corrupted files they would be messed up (e.g. partially rendered for jpegs, clicking noises and skipping for mp3s). Fortunately, of the 250 files, they were all either files I didn't care about, or else files that I already had sufficient previous backups of.
It also identified about 200 unrecovered filesystem blocks which were not associated with any files. I was not really sure what to do about these. Looking at the output of dumpe2fs, it did not seem like these were blocks that contained filesystem metadata. But they were also not marked as free. So not sure exactly what they are.
After this, you can run fsck. Although for some reason I don't understand fsck command itself did nothing, and I need to instead run e2fsck:
# Because we previously ran kpartx with -r option, the filesystem can't be modified, need to undo everything and redo it without -r
sudo umount /path/to/mount/point
# need to run these two commands in immediate succession, that's why they are combined on one line:
sudo vgchange -an && sudo cryptsetup close try1
sudo kpartx -d /media/ubuntu/whatever/rescue.img
# redo:
sudo kpartx -a /media/ubuntu/whatever/rescue.img
sudo cryptsetup open /dev/mapper/loop14p6 try1
sudo vgchange -ay
# fsck doesn't do anything (?), using e2fsck directly
sudo e2fsck -y -f /dev/vgubuntu/root

fsck will find a lot of errors, but fortunately nothing catastrophic in my case.
At this point, you can mount your drive and copy all the files you want off it.
